# Invalid csrf token issue express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, multer

I am trying to implement csrf tokens for the first time and i am running into issues. I've been working at it for a few hours and haven't been able to solve it. Below is the error I am getting:

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = require('./router')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const csrf = require('csurf')
dotenv.config()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cookieParser('secret'))
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    cookie: {maxAge: null},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(flash())
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(csrf())
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken()
    next()
})
app.use('/', router)


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render('404')
  })
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).render('404')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const multerConfigOpts = require('./multer.config')
const router = express.Router()
const userController = require('./controllers/userController')
const csrf = require('csurf')
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
// set multer configuration options
const upload = multer(multerConfigOpts)


router.get('/', userController.home)
router.get('/about', userController.about)
router.get('/employer', userController.employer)
router.get('/jobSeeker', userController.jobSeeker)
router.get('/ourProcess', userController.process)
router.get('/contact', userController.contactUs)

// Talent Request Post related routes
router.post('/talentrequest',upload.none() ,userController.requestTalent)

// Job Request Post related routs
router.post('/jobrequest', csrfProtection, upload.single('resume'), userController.requestJob)

module.exports = router
```

**Example of my form:**

```
            <form action="/jobrequest" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn--form-submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

There are more data fields, I just didn't want to bloat the question with unnecessary code. I've been reading that others are having similar issues when using multipart in the form, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I know that my token is being generated inside the form but I'm not sure if its being passed through properly. Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a work around solution by adding the following to my form and removing the `input hidden field` from my form

```
form action="/talentrequest/*?_csrf=<%= csrfToken %>*" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Everything works as it should. Can anyone explain the potential risks involved with this?